# Shortcode display product custom field value

Tags: woocommerce, attributes, product

In WooCommerce, I would like to display a table on a custom page with a list of (downloadable) products with their title and attribute / custom field values.

For the product title  in the first column of my table I'm using the following shortcode:

```
[product _name id="9"]
```

The code in my funcions.php file

```
function displayProductName($item) { 
    $productName = get_the_title($item['id']); 
    return $productName; 
} 
add_shortcode('product_name', 'displayProductName');
```

In the second column I'd like to display the value of a custom added field (with advanced custom fields): field is File Version (slug file-version), value is 1.22

I can't seem to figure out how to translate this into a working function.

So what I would like is to display the value of a custom field based on a single product ID on a random page with a shortcode.

Any ideas would be very appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack exchange! I suggested an edit to your question to properly format your code. Read the help in the question editor for more info. Also please include some more context about which technologies/PHP packages you use. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, it improves your chances to get an answer and makes life for all of us easier.

Answer (score 1):

After doing more research, I managed to find the solution, which was much easier than I thought.

Since I'm using Advanced custom Fields, I could use their shortcode.

So for example, I have custom field Download Version (slug: download_version) that I use for downloadable products.

To display the value of Download Version for a specific product, on a random page, I used the shortcode

```
[acf field="download_version" post_id="9"]
```

Where the product ID is 9.

Maybe useful for other users who want to do the same...